# connect one model to different database servers(sql, teradata) in sails

Tags: sails.js

Is there a way to connect a model to different databases in sails? I am using sails 0.12 version and have to populate one database with the data from different databases. Is there a way in sails to do this? The database i want to populate to is sqlserver. and the other database that i want to make connection to are mysql and teradata.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple connection in sails and then use any connection in model, settings for multiple connections can be found in config/connection.js [Documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/config/connections.js)
Default connection setting wil be found in config/model.js unless you override them.

Comment: yes, i think this is for multiple connection for multiple models. I want to use multiple connection in same model so that same model can use different connection.

Comment: In your model you can define connection to use module.exports = {  
  connection:'mysql',
  attributes: {

    name : { type: 'string' },

    title : { type: 'string' },

    date : { type: 'date' }
  }
};